# Compatible version of ubuntu 64 bit with intel processor

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I want to know which version of ubuntu is compatible with my machine.

My PC configuration is:

Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo
RAM : 3 GB
System Type : 64-bit

I have currently installed windows 7 on my machine. Now I want to install Ubuntu 64 bit as well so that I can dual boot. I have tried with [ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64](http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso) but am getting an error in installation.

I want to know which version of Ubuntu is compatible for my machine.
Should I go with [ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386](http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso) ?

Comment: nope, its on topic here. Saying what error would help - but there's no reason ubuntu 64bit (AKA AMD64) shouldn't work. You can still use the 32 bit build (AKA i386) - 32 bit can address 3gb.

Comment: Would help to know what the error was...

Answer (score 1):

The AMD64 version of Ubuntu is compatible with EM64T processors.